# Why do all objects have enough generalized elements?

Tags: category-theory

I understand why in the category of sets two parallel morphisms $f, g: A \rightarrow B$ are identical iff for each *element* $x: 1 \rightarrow A$ it holds that $f\circ x = g \circ x$.

Awodey on p. 36 of *Category Theory* asks (as an exercise), why in *any* category two parallel morphisms $f, g: A \rightarrow B$ are identical iff for each *generalized element* $x: X \rightarrow A$ it holds that $f\circ x = g \circ x$.

Could someone please give me a hint how to prove this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just let $X=A$ and $x$ be the identity morphism.

Comment: It's so simple?

Comment: @Hans: It couldn't really be anything else, since in general there's no reason for there to *be* any other morphisms into $A$.

Comment: and the converse?

Comment: The hint in the book was that this had to be the case for "each generalized element x:X→A" . If only one relation had sufficed then the question would have been phrased differently. [NLab seems to suggest](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element) that this is related to the Yoneda Embedding, but that is beyond my ability to understand. An answer that explains this intuitively would be nice.

Comment: The article is "[Doing without Diagrams](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/elements.pdf) by Tom Leinster.

Comment: The article by "[Doing Without Diagrams](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/elements.pdf)" by Tom Leinster on the other hand seems to confirm the above answer...

Comment: just to add, the converse is immediate, due to the congruence of morphism composition.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a way to see this using Yoneda's embedding, too; I post it because it has been mentioned in the comments.

Fix any category $\mathbf C$ and two arrows $f,g:C\to C'$. The Yoneda embedding $y:\mathbf C\to \mathbf{Set}$ is a fully faithful functor, hence $f=g$ if and only if $y(f)=y(g)$. By definition, $y(f):\mathbf C(-,C)\to \mathbf C(-,C')$ is the natural transformation whose component $y(f)_D:\mathbf C(D,C)\to \mathbf C(D,C')$, for every object $D$, sends any $h:D\to C$ to $f\circ h$; and similarly for $y(g)$. But $y(f)=y(g)$ if and only if $y(f)_D=y(g)_D$ for every object $D$, that is, $f\circ h=g\circ h$ for every generalized element $h:D\to C$.

Yoneda's lemma asserts that two natural transformations $\alpha,\beta$ from $\mathbf C(-,C)$ to any functor $\mathbf C\to \mathbf{Set}$ coincide  if and only if $\alpha_C(\operatorname{id}_C)=\beta_C(\operatorname{id}_C)$; thus, it is a way of seeing that $y(f)=y(g)$ if and only if $f\circ \operatorname{id}_C=g\circ \operatorname{id}_C$.